How to make the computer try to attack or defend in gomoku game using python?
I'm writing a program that simulates a player-versus-computer python game. The program has been running stably. However, when checking, the machine plays very randomly, with no attack or defense at all. If I research, I will use the minmax algorithm to process. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me? My python code is:
import random
import math

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" | ".join(row))
        print("-" * 100)

def check_winner(board, player):
    for row in board:
        if all([cell == player for cell in row]):
            return True
    for col in range(15):
        if all([board[row][col] == player for row in range(15)]):
            return True
    if all([board[i][i] == player for i in range(15)]) or all([board[i][2-i] == player for i in range(15)]):
        return True
    return False

def bot_move(board):
    for row in range(15):
        for col in range(15):
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "O"
                if check_winner(board, "O"):
                    return (row, col)
                board[row][col] = " "
    for row in range(15):
        for col in range(15):
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "X"
                if check_winner(board, "X"):
                    board[row][col] = "O"
                    return (row, col)
                board[row][col] = " "
    while True:
        row = random.randint(0, 14)
        col = random.randint(0, 14)
        if board[row][col] == " ":
            return (row, col)
def play_game():
    board = [[" " for _ in range(15)] for _ in range(15)]
    player = "X"
    while True:
        print_board(board)
        if check_winner(board, "X"):
            print("Player X wins!")
            break
        if check_winner(board, "O"):
            print("Player O wins!")
            break
        if all([cell != " " for row in board for cell in row]):
            print("It's a draw!")
            break
        if player == "X":
            row, col = map(int, input("Enter your move (row col): ").split())
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "X"
                player = "O"
        else:
            row, col = bot_move(board)
            board[row][col] = "O"
            player = "X"

play_game()

X is player, O is computer
Result of my code
